# Solving Trig with Double Angle Identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I'm working on an answer key for a worksheet in my Precalc class and I came across the following problem:

$$-\cos \theta+ \sin \theta = 1$$ on the interval $$0 \le \theta < 2\pi$$

I go through solving this to get to the point where I have:
$-2\cos \theta \sin \theta = 0$ and I used the zero product property to get that:

$\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}\ $, $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2}\ ,$ $\theta = 0 $, and $\theta = \pi $.

I eliminated the extraneous solutions of $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2}\ $ and $\theta = 0 $ to get a final answer of:

$\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}\ $ and $\theta = \pi $

My issue is that I also noticed that $-2\cos \theta \sin \theta$ can be rewritten as $-\sin 2\theta$ from the double angle identity and this would give me solutions of:

$2\theta = 0$ and $2\theta = \pi$ so $\theta = 0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}\ $.

Again, $0$ is extraneous but I'm missing the other solution of $\pi$ that I get using the other solution method.

Is the worksheet possibly looking at the interval $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ or did I do something something incorrectly?

Comment: Another way to do this problem that avoids extraneous solutions is: \begin{align*} \sin\theta - \cos\theta & = 1\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\theta - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\theta & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \sin\theta\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) - \cos\theta\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \sin\left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{align*} from which we conclude that $\theta - \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\theta - \frac{\pi}{4} = \pi - \frac{\pi}{4}$, which yields the solutions $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\theta = \pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the solutions to $\sin2\theta=0$ also includes

$$2\theta=2\pi$$

which gives you the expect solution $\theta = \pi$.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by includes?  Using the double angle identities changes the domain?

Comment: @ColinSuehring - Given $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$, you have $2\theta\in [0,4\pi)$. So, $2\theta =2\pi $ is also a solution.